# How to map a local directory to a localhost URL using Apache?

Tags: apache2, php

I just want to put a simple PHP website in a custom directory on my machine (say /home/znorg/foobar) and access it though apache2 on Ubuntu through something like http://localhost/foobar/

Sorry if this is a repeated or too trivial a question, but I just can't find a straightforward answer on how to do just that anywhere.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for http://serverfault.com/ than  for http://askubuntu.com . I suggest you to ask this question there for better help.

Comment: create file in `/home/znorg/foobar` symbolically link it to `/var/www/html/foobar`, then create a _virtual host_ in `/etc/apache2/site-available/foobar.conf` which you enable with `sudo e2ensite foobar.conf`. With that you can do `localhost/foobar`

Comment: This link might help you:
http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach is to: *Maps URLs to filesystem locations* via Apache's configuration. For this purpose you must use the directive [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias). The syntax is:

```
Alias [URL-path] file-path|directory-path
```

Please note that [`mod_alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) is required, but it comes with Apache2 by default. You can check if it is installed through:

```
sudo apache2ctl -M | grep alias
```

Alias can be used for directories and for files. Also it can be used at both levels:

- Server-level (in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or in `/etc/apache2/conf-avaliable/myAlias.conf`) - the alias will be available for each active Virtualhost;
- VHost-level (in `/etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/someVH.conf`; in between `<VirtualHost >` tags) - the alias will be available only for the current VirtualHost.

> Note that you may need to specify additional `<Directory>` sections
>   which cover the *destination* of aliases. Aliasing occurs before
>   `<Directory>` sections are checked, so only the destination of aliases
>   are affected.
>
> In particular, if you are creating an Alias to a directory outside of
>   your `DocumentRoot`, you may need to explicitly permit access to the
>   target directory.

Here you are a list of some [pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6561994/6543935) of the two approaches: Alias and SymLinks. Also [check this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889625/how-to-map-a-local-directory-to-a-localhost-url-using-apache#comment1392759_889770) comment.

### Example 1 : Alias at VHost-level

---

Let's assume you want to make an Alias at VirtualHost-level and your VH configuration file is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`. In this case the configuration file should looks something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # other VirtualHost directives

    Alias /foobar /home/znorg/foobar
    <Directory /home/znorg/foobar>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to restart (or reload) the server:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

### Example 2 : Alias at Server-level

---

Let's assume you want to make an Alias at Server-level and you don't want to touch `apache2.conf`. In this case you have to create and enable an additional configuration file. In our example this is `foobarAlias.conf`, which must be placed in the directory `/etc/apache2/conf-available/`.

You can create this file through (use ctrl+o for save and ctrl+x for exit):

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/foobarAlias.conf
```

And its content should looks something like this:

```
Alias /foobar /home/znorg/foobar
<Directory /home/znorg/foobar>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Don't forget to enable the new configuration and restart (or reload) the server:

```
sudo a2enconf foobarAlias && sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Comment: This is probably a more elegant solution, thanks!

Comment: Both solutions are appropriate in different cases. For example the entire program PHPMyAdmin is included into Apache's configuration through the way, shown here. But if you have a mixed content like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQGfJ.png), maybe symlinks are more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @George's comment above, this is what worked for me:

1) Create symbolic link in `/var/www/html` to desired directory:

```
sudo ln -s /home/znorg/foobar /var/www/html/foobar
```

2) Copy template configuration file:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/foobar.conf
```

3) Then in foobar.conf, search for a line like:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

And replace `/var/www/html` with `/home/znorg/foobar`

4) Enable the new configuration:

```
sudo a2ensite foobar
```

5) Reload the server:

```
service apache2 reload
```

Hope this is useful for someone else.

Comment: You don't need to create new configuration file, just create new <Directory> definition between the tags `<VirtualHost *:80>` ... `</VirtualHost>`.